# Connecting Android with PHP, MySQL -Emulator

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-emulator

> I am connecting android to mysql database using php but emulator fails to launch the application

I have followed  line by line of this Tutorial:

> [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Can anyone please tell me what does this Logcat Ouptut means

### Console Output

```
[2014-07-05 17:44:33 - MainScreenActivity] ------------------------------
[2014-07-05 17:44:33 - MainScreenActivity] Android Launch!
[2014-07-05 17:44:33 - MainScreenActivity] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-05 17:44:33 - MainScreenActivity] Performing com.example.mainscreenactivity.FullscreenActivity activity launch
[2014-07-05 17:44:33 - MainScreenActivity] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Dev' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-07-05 17:44:33 - MainScreenActivity] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Dev'
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:41 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2014-07-05 17:44:46 - MainScreenActivity] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-07-05 17:44:46 - MainScreenActivity] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-07-05 17:50:32 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument
[2014-07-05 17:50:32 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev
[2014-07-05 17:51:48 - MainScreenActivity] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.mainscreenactivity.FullscreenActivity activity launch'!
```

### LogCat

```
07-05 13:14:46.188: D/AndroidRuntime(1780): Shutting down VM
07-05 13:14:46.188: W/dalvikvm(1780): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1e03ce8)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780): Process: com.example.mainscreenactivity, PID: 1780
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mainscreenactivity/com.example.mainscreenactivity.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mainscreenactivity.FullscreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mainscreenactivity-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mainscreenactivity-1, /system/lib]]
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2123)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mainscreenactivity.FullscreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mainscreenactivity-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mainscreenactivity-1, /system/lib]]
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
07-05 13:14:46.268: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Restart your eclipse and create a new AVD(If needed) and go on.

Comment: @APriya I had done that twice i am a newbie in android so basically I am stuck here